# CSS forced wrap

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

In the first picture, the circled areas are two **inline-block div** elements.
Currently when i make the browser window smaller the second div element jumps under the first one as expected.
What i want is to make the text inside the second div element to wrap when i make the window smaller and to keep the space under the first div element empty.

[image: big window]

[image: small window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your answers. Finally i got the result i wanted with this:

```
<div id="big">
  <div id="left">
    <div>#15</div>
    <div>OPEN</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>TODO: add a destination for Hello, User hyperlink</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
#big {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width:100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div, p {
    margin:0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just add this CSS property:

```css
word-wrap: break-word;
/* To break the text */
```

Also, you are not supposed to use inline-blocks for this purpose.
Instead, use flexbox or grid.
Example:

```html
<section>
 <div class="details">
 </div>
 <div class="description">
  <p> Text </p>
 </div>
</section>
```

```css
section {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;

}

.details {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.description {
 width: 100%;
 grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.description p {
 word-wrap: break-word; /* Will break the text*/
}
```

Comment: This is almost what i was looking for. The only problem is that <div class="details"> should be a fixed size and not relative to content. I can't get that working with the code you provided.

Comment: Hello, I updated the answer, it should work now. Also, you can change the grid-template-columns 250px to different value to change size of details. If it works, then mark it as answer, if not, you have to share more details or it will not be possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flexbox :)

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

div>div:first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div>div>div:last-child {
  background: orange;
}

div>div:last-child p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>#15</div>
    <div>OPEN</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>TODO: add a destination for Hello, User hyperlink</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Stuhlmann/pen/vYKqMNW)

Comment: I think you did not mean to set this rule also : `flex-flow: row wrap;` the op wants to keep both on the same line/row.